# how to add number value in front for variable

Tags: php, variables, code

Hi there my question is very simple, is there a way by which we can add a value in the end of the variable a numeric value.

like we have a variable

```
$tota
$tota1
$tota2
$tota3
```

each have different value what I want here is to use a function that first write 1 in front of variable

something like

```
echo $tota . 1 ;
```

But its not working the php taking 1 as a different entity.

please note array is not a option I can use I want above function as describe.
I don't want whole function I just want a technique that add number after variable.

Comment: Who upvoted this..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Very simple you can implement like this

```
${variable_name}.another_varibale;
```

For Example

```
for($i=1;$i<10; $i++)
{
   ${total}.$i = 10+$i;
}

for(j=1;j<10;j++
{
    echo ${total}.$i;
}
```